# python: ast.literal_eval() gives ValueError: malformed string

Tags: python

I've read quite a few other posts on this forum regarding this particular error, but nothing has really helped me solve my problem.

Basically I've got something like this:

```
{' Marie ': ' (ENG,80) (PHY,65) (CHEM,80) '}
```

I'm trying to convert the above into:

```
[(ENG,80),(PHY,65),(CHEM,80)]
```

so that I can access each grade of the tuple and add them up and return the result.

My attempt so far has been :

```
>>> N={' Marie ': ' (ENG,80) (PHY,65) (CHEM,80) '}
>>> q= N.items()
>>> q
[(' Marie ', ' (ENG,80) (PHY,65) (CHEM,80) ')]
>>> r=N.values()[0]
>>> r
' (ENG,80) (PHY,65) (CHEM,80) '
>>> y=r.strip().split()
>>> y
['(ENG,80)', '(PHY,65)', '(CHEM,80)']
>>> remove=",".join(y)
>>> remove
'(ENG,80),(PHY,65),(CHEM,80)'
>>> list(ast.literal_eval(remove))
ValueError: malformed string
```

How can I achieve the desired result?
Is it possible to do so directly from the dictionary?

Comment: Strings should be enclosed with `'` or `"`

Comment: `'(ENG,80),(PHY,65),(CHEM,80)'` is not a valid literal, because `ENG` and `PHY` and `CHEM` are not quoted. They are not strings, they would be *names* in Python code but names are not literal syntax.

Comment: I'm a newb, and so I don't understand why your example is not a literal. Aren't literals enclosed in quotes? What is the exception that makes this not a literal `'(ENG,80),(PHY,65),(CHEM,80)'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The string `'(ENG,80),(PHY,65),(CHEM,80)'` is not a valid Python literal. Presumably you want `ENG`, `PHY` and `CHEM` to be treated as strings, but they are not quoted to be valid Python string literals.

Just parse this part manually:

```
N = {' Marie ': ' (ENG,80) (PHY,65) (CHEM,80) '} 
value = N.values()[0]
output = [(token, int(num)) for tup in value.split() for token, num in (tup.strip('()').split(','),)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> N = {' Marie ': ' (ENG,80) (PHY,65) (CHEM,80) '}
>>> value = N.values()[0]
>>> [(token, int(num)) for tup in value.split() for token, num in (tup.strip('()').split(','),)]
[('ENG', 80), ('PHY', 65), ('CHEM', 80)]
```